# Quantitative trading

Tags: soft-question, math-software

What math subjects are used in quantitative trading firms?

Comment: @KerxPhilo Your question needs to be far more specific than this in order for it not to be considered off-topic.  You can find mathematicians trained in most subfield of math employed at quant trading firms.  The head of the richest one is a differential geometer! (And not a statistician as one might presume.)

Comment: @Billare, which quant trading firm are you referring to regarding the differential geometer?

Comment: @KerxPhilo Jim Simons of Renaissance Technologies.  Along with SS Chern, he has a whole theory named after him that finds prominent use in theoretical physics.  In any case, that's not what I come here to talk about.

Comment: @Billare, I appreciate it, sorry to take you off your path.

Comment: @KerxPhilo No problem, I hope I don't come off as rude or overly brusque.  This would be interesting to talk about in another context, I think, but it's off-topic as stated here.

Comment: @KerxPhilo You should try asking on quant.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start with topics such as

- Probability
- Statistics
- Analysis and calculus
- Stochastic processes and stochastic calculus
- Numerical methods
- Computational methods
- Modelling
- Optimisation
- Decision theory
- Data mining
- Time series
- Operational research
- Mathematical finance
- Mathematical economics
- Mathematical psychology

and the list could go on

Comment: +1 for the absurdity of that long of a list (I don't mean any offense).  It shows the question needs some focus.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon Quantstart.com, lately. There is a series of articles, called "How to learn advanced mathematics without heading to university", which gives an answer to your question in great detail:

[Part 1](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/How-to-Learn-Advanced-Mathematics-Without-Heading-to-University-Part-1/)

[Part 2](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/How-to-Learn-Advanced-Mathematics-Without-Heading-to-University-Part-2/)

[Part 3](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/How-to-Learn-Advanced-Mathematics-Without-Heading-to-University-Part-3/)

[Part 4](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/how-to-learn-advanced-mathematics-without-heading-to-university-part-4/)